# Change the content of a ttkbootstrap ScrolledFrame

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

How do I replace the content of a `ttkbootstrap ScrolledFrame`?

I have built the scrolled frame with this snippet:

```py
        for ndx, t in enumerate(sorted(tw, key=lambda x: x.created_at, reverse=True)):
            print(t.created_at)
            card = make_tweet_card(t, tweet_detail_scroller)
            card.grid(pady=5, row=ndx, column=0, sticky="W")
```

Based on a button click I need to empty the `ScrolledFrame` and replace the content with different content.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed a separate list of the content before I could iterate through it for destruction.

The snippet is now:

```py
        if len(tweet_detail_scroller.children) > 0:
            content = [cw for cw in tweet_detail_scroller.children.values()]
            for cw in content:
                cw.destroy()
        for ndx, t in enumerate(sorted(tw, key=lambda x: x.created_at, reverse=True)):
            print(t.created_at)
            card = make_tweet_card(t, tweet_detail_scroller)
            card.grid(pady=5, row=ndx, column=0, sticky="W")
```

where `tw` contains the new list of tweets.

Comment: There is no `tw` must be `cw`